# In generalized mixed-effects model, after fixed effects and variance covariance matrix are fitted, how are empirical random effects calculated?

Tags: logistic, mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, random-effects-model

For example, I would like to fit a logistic mixed-effects model.

This article [fitting glmm](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3175267/) talks about how to fit fixed effects as well as variance covariance matrix of random effects. Theoretically we can use maximum likelihood estimator like this.

[image: Model specification]

[image: log likelihood]

But I do not know how to compute the empirical random effects for all groups. In linear mixed-effects model, we can calculate EBLUPS(empirical best linear unbiased predictors) of random effects easily. In generalized linear model, the only method I know is to calculate the posterior distribution of random effects for each group, i.e. $(b_i|x_{it},\beta, y_{it})$, and then calculate the maximum likelihood estimator for each group.

Is there any better method?

In addition, why don't people maximize the joint distribution of $(y_{it}, \beta, b_i, \Sigma_b)$? In this way we can get all the estimates together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, when fitting mixed models with maximum likelihood, estimates for the random effects are obtained in a second step using emprical Bayes methodology. In your example, suppose that $\hat \theta = (\hat \beta^\top, \mbox{vech}(\hat \Sigma_b)^\top)^\top$ denote the maximum likelihood estimates for the fixed effects $\beta$ and the unique element of the covariance matrix $\Sigma_b$. Then, the empirical Bayes estimates of the random effects are the modes of the posterior distribution $$p(b_i \mid y_i; \hat\theta) = \frac{p(y_i \mid b_i; \hat \beta) \; p(b_i; \hat \Sigma_b)}{p(y_i; \hat\theta)}, $$ which are typically found by numerically maximizing the log of the numerator, i.e., $$\hat b_i = \arg\max_b \{\log p(y_i \mid b; \hat \beta) + \log p(b; \hat \Sigma_b)\}.$$

A reason why in classical maximum likelihood you do not maximize the log likelihood $\log p(y, b, \beta, \Sigma_b)$ w.r.t. all $(b, \beta, \Sigma_b)$ is because you have the requirement that the dimension of the parameter space is bounded and does not increase with the sample size $n$. If you would treat the random effects $b_i$ as parameters, you have that as $n$ increases, the dimensionality of the parameter space would also increase. In the literature there have been some alternative estimation approaches proposed that do that, such as H-likelihood; however, they have not (yet) displaced the classical maximum likelihood as the primary estimation approach for mixed models.