# Why are fisher-scoring estimates of the fixed-effects not used to calculate empirical bayes estimates of random-effects? Are they in-admissible?

Tags: mixed-model, generalized-estimating-equations, empirical-bayes, admissibility, fisher-scoring

Why is it not practiced using estimates of fixed-effects from fisher scoring used to calculate GEE coefficients to estimate random-effects via empirical bayes? We have another estimate of $\theta$ in GEE.

> Indeed, when fitting mixed models with maximum likelihood, estimates for the random effects are obtained in a second step using emprical Bayes methodology. In your example, suppose that $\hat{\theta}=\left(\hat{\beta}^{\top}, \operatorname{vech}\left(\hat{\Sigma}_{b}\right)^{\top}\right)^{\top}$ denote the maximum likelihood estimates for the fixed effects $\beta$ and the unique element of the covariance matrix $\Sigma_{b}$. Then, the empirical Bayes estimates of the random effects are the modes of the posterior distribution
> $$
> p\left(b_{i} \mid y_{i} ; \hat{\theta}\right)=\frac{p\left(y_{i} \mid b_{i} ; \hat{\beta}\right) p\left(b_{i} ; \hat{\Sigma}_{b}\right)}{p\left(y_{i} ; \hat{\theta}\right)}
> $$
> which are typically found by numerically maximizing the log of the numerator, i.e.,
> $$
> \hat{b}_{i}=\arg \max _{b}\left\{\log p\left(y_{i} \mid b ; \hat{\beta}\right)+\log p\left(b ; \hat{\Sigma}_{b}\right)\right\}
> $$

[In generalized mixed-effects model, after fixed effects and variance covariance matrix are fitted, how are empirical random effects calculated?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/396939/in-generalized-mixed-effects-model-after-fixed-effects-and-variance-covariance)

Comment: Hi, maybe I misunderstood, but you're asking about the variable $\hat{b}_i$, right? What you quoted doesn't actually say anything about how the maximization is conducted, why wouldn't fisher scoring (viewed as one of many possible preconditioners, though admittedly a darn good one, for gradient descent) be allowable as a means by which to conduct the $\mathrm{arg}\underset{b}{\mathrm{max}}$ operation?

Comment: @JohnMadden, yes.I'm saying substitute fisher-scoring estimates for Maximum-likelihood, why not do it? Aside, is using MAP instead of MLE called using fully-bayesian random-effects?

Comment: If we mean the same Fisher Scoring estimates, they're the same thing as the MLE: Fisher Scoring is a particular algorithm that solves the maximum likelihood optimization problem. Regarding your aside: No, fully-Bayesian random effects would try to provide some more full characterization of the posterior than MAP, which just tells you its mode. Typically, when people talk about fully-Bayesian inference inpractice, they mean inference on Bayesian models using Markov chain Monte-Carlo.